# Unsigned Integer Multiple Syntax

Tags: c++, types, unsigned-integer

I am new to c++ and was wondering if there is a difference between `uint32_t` and `tUInt32` ?
Is it just syntactic sugar ?
Or is it just a result of `using namespace std;`?

I know what they represent (see: https://www.badprog.com/c-type-what-are-uint8-t-uint16-t-uint32-t-and-uint64-t ). I am simply confused why two different ways to represent them exist and which to use.

Although I have searched SO with `uint32_t` and `tUInt32`, I hope this is not a duplicate.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tUInt32` doesn't seem to be standard. I found a reference to it [here](http://devlib.symbian.slions.net/s3/GUID-251A35C1-CC66-4DE4-9EBE-964026E89E7F/GUID-FC2F2B93-3D18-3BCC-9FD6-6BC6B240B667.html) in the Symbian OS docs, which defines it as a `typedef` of `unsigned long int`, which is not guaranteed to be the same as `uint32_t` (`uint32_t` is [guaranteed to be 32 bits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), whereas `unsigned long int` [is not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) in general - Symbian may guarantee it is 32 bits, but I can't find a reference for this).

Comment: It might be guaranteed, because that's what the architecture says though, no?

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I am working in a Linux Environment and it seems to be working fine. Thank you very much, how did you find that document if I may ask ? I have searched for a while before coming here.

Comment: @hammeramr I just searched for `tUint32` on google, saw quite a few references to Symbian OS, and on the first google link found it's definition within Symbian.